# Was the alien in the yellow armor helping the humans?

Tags: movie, battleship

After having watched the movie *Battleship*, there were a number of things that I did not understand. One of which was the role of the (scientist/engineer?) alien in the (yellow?) armor.

On at least two occasions, it encountered main characters and did not alert the soldiers. Once at the wreckage of the police Jeeps, and once when the geek went to collect his transmitter.

Was it grateful for being dragged from the sea early in the movie (or even the same character), feeling guilty about overrunning another planet, or just a big softy?

Comment: See previous questions on Battleship.  The whole movie makes very little sense.

Comment: @BBlake I understand, but this is not a contrivance where they are twisting the story to fit the rules of a board game, or a failure of science where they get the physics wrong. The writer and the director were trying to communicate something relating to the character of the alien, and failed (for me). That makes it a riddle to be answered.

Comment: You know, this might be a better question for the [Movies and TV beta](http://movies.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 5):

The way I understand it, those who weren't seen as a direct threat weren't engaged. Just like the kid at the ball field or when the naval warships' guns where turned away from their craft. To take the risk of a cross-universe reference... they acted a bit like the Borg in how they were going about their business. What was perceived as a direct threat was engaged and crushed but a non-threat was basically ignored as they went about their tasks.

They even had a color code; Red=attack, Green=ignore.